# Can't query a node with xpath query

Tags: xpath

I am having some difficulty querying a node in an xml document. the document is http://ods.od.nih.gov/api/index.aspx?resourcename=BotanicalBackground&readinglevel=Health%20Professional

i am trying to get the text of the first  node.

i have tried these queries and none of them seemed to work.

```
*[name()='ImageURL']
//captionedimage[1]
//Factsheet/RelatedImages/captionedimage[1]/ImageURL/text()
//RelatedImages/*[1]
```

greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Have you registered and used the namespaces which are used in the xml?

Comment: it's done within drupal feeds. but i am just using an online test like this one to test. http://www.xpathtester.com/test

Comment: drupal means: you need a php example?

Comment: well. it's using the feed module to import the xml doc. so no i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your three last XPATH seem to be working (you can quickly check it out at http://www.xpathtester.com/test or http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html). The problem should be linked to the environment you use.

When I tried them on scrapy the uppercases XPATH retrieved nothing, only `//factsheet/relatedimages/captionedimage[1]/imageurl/text()` seemed to be working. Sadly, this behavior is surprising to me and I have no idea why it acted that way. But you should definitely try and gather more info on the environment you're using.

Comment: hmm weird. i just tried them on the sites you provided. they didnt seem to work.

Comment: retried the last one. it does work. ended up doing //RelatedImages/*[1]/*[1]

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

./Factsheet/RelatedImages/*[local-name() = 'captionedimage' and position()=1]/*[local-name() = 'ImageURL']

Comment: i get an invalid expression.